# MongoDB aggregate, unwind, group (same array)?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection ("items") with the following schema:

```
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
    },
  description: String,
  categories: [String]
});

mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema, 'items');
```

Each item can have more than one category (categories [String]). I'm using the following javascript to try to get all the items grouped by the unwound categories array elements.

```
const itemsGetAllByCategory = function (req, res) { 
Item    
    .aggregate( [
            { '$unwind' : '$categories' }, 
            { '$group' : 
                { '_id': '$categories',
                    'elements': { '$push': 
                      {'name': '$name', 
                       'description': '$description' }
                    }
                }
            }
    ]) 
    .sort({'_id': 1})
    .exec((err, items) => {
        if (err) {
            res
              .status(404)
              .json(err);
        } 
        else {
            res
                .status(200)
                .json(items);
        }
    });
};
```

Data:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5be0f88e7b1b91424006d597"),
"name" : "Item 1",
"description" : "Description of Item 1",
"categories" : "[\"Category A\", \"Category B\", \"Category C\"]"
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5be0f88e7b1b91424006d598"),
"name" : "Item 2",
"description" : "Description of Item 2",
"categories" : "[\"Category A\", \"Category B\"]"
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5be0f88e7b1b91424006d599"),
"name" : "Item 3",
"description" : "Description of Item 3",
"categories" : "[\"Category A\"]"
}
```

I would like the resulting output to be:

```
[{"_id":"Category A",
  "elements":[
   {"name":"Item 1","description":"Description of Item 1"},
   {"name":"Item 2","description":"Description of Item 2"}, 
   {"name":"Item 3","description":"Description of Item 3"}]},
 {"_id":"Category B",
  "elements":[
   {"name":"Item 1","description":"Description of Item 1"},
   {"name":"Item 2","description":"Description of Item 2"}]},
 {"_id":"Category B",
  "elements":[
   {"name":"Item 1","description":"Description of Item 1"}]}]
```

However, this code is giving me the following output:

```
[{"_id":"[\"Category A\", \"Category B\", \"Category C\"]",
  "elements":[
    {"name":"Item 1","description":"Description of Item 1"}]},
 {"_id":"[\"Category A\", \"Category B\"]",
  "elements":[
    {"name":"Item 2","description":"Description of Item 2"}]},
 {"_id":"[\"Category A\"]",
  "elements":[
    {"name":"Item 3","description":"Description of Item 3"}]}]
```

The $unwind call doesn't seem to be giving me the multiple output documents I expect for anything with more than one category, and the grouped categories remain as arrays instead of individual strings. Is there an issue with the code for unwind() or group() or both?

Comment: Based on the content here nobody will be able to reproduce as the expected output would be returned. If you still think you have a problem then I suggest 1. Include the **full** aggregation pipeline, since your truncated input suggests you're doing other things than the displayed stages and that is where your problem likely is. 2. Show a small sample of actual data which can along with the full supplied pipeline **reproduce the issue**. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're telling us what you "see", but it's not "complete"

Comment: updated, sorry about that. thanks.

Comment: Because "categories" is a "string" and NOT an array. I would have actually expected the pipeline to fail with an error to indicate that. Possibly you're actual data might contain a single entry array which is the string? But the main point is the data is stored incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was in the database:

```
categories: "[\"Category A\", \"Category B\", \"Category C\"]"
```

should have been:

```
categories: ["Category A", "Category B", "Category C"]
```

The quotes before the opening brackets and after the closing brackets were causing the entry to be stored as single strings rather than arrays of strings.  Thanks to [Neil Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn) for suggesting I provide more detail, which caused me to notice this.